# Why infinity to power 0 is implemented to be 1?

Tags: javascript, python, math, infinity

This is an undeterminate form in Math, but in Python and JavaScript it results in 1.
Tested in

Python:

```py
inf=float('inf')
print(inf**0)
```

JavaScript

```js
console.log(Math.pow(Infinity,0))
console.log(Infinity**0)
```

Comment: What would you expect the result to be? Anything raised to the power 0 is 1 by mathematical definition.

Comment: Well... [Zero to the power of zero, denoted by 00, is a mathematical expression with no agreed-upon value.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero)

Comment: @ThierryLathuille sure but that's not what this question is about.

Comment: It's a case of something at the power 0 that isn't so clearly mathematically defined.

Comment: Well IEEE 754 math is pretty thoroughly specified. "why" questions like this are not really useful.

Comment: I think that referring to IEEE 754 is the right answer, though. It says in 6.1 - infinity arithmetics: 'The behavior of infinity in floating-point arithmetic is derived from the limiting cases of real arithmetic with operands of arbitrarily large magnitude, when such a limit exists.' So, of course, 1 makes total sense.

Comment: Don't confuse being an indeterminate form with being undefined. They're not the same thing. It's perfectly fine to define infinity**0 to be 1 while still describing it as an indeterminate form in the context of evaluating limits.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille: Note that IEEE 754 hedges its bets on this topic, though. It defines various power operations, including one called `powr` for which `powr(+∞, ±0)` signals the invalid operation exception. (See section 9.2.1 of the 2019 IEEE 754 revision.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just the way the specification is defined:

> #### 6.1.6.1.3 Number::exponentiate ( *base*, *exponent* )
>
> Returns an implementation-dependent approximation of the result of raising base to the power exponent.
>
> If exponent is NaN, the result is NaN.
> **If exponent is +0, the result is 1**, even if base is NaN.
> [...]

Source: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-exponentiate (emphasis by answerer)